Futuristic prison where they could read prisoners' minds

Prison movie from the 90s
Sci fi future looking
They could read the prisoners' minds
Somebody steals some bread and gets punished
Early stage of movie, they're on board a train and a guard says no talking

Which movie is this?

I think as below it's Fortress, trains easily confused with Train, I don't think the bread is stolen, it's hoarded, one of the other prisoners saved some and tried to share it with Brennick

The other movie it sounds like (apart from the mind reading) is "Escape From Absolom" also called "No Escape" with Ray Liotta.
But I think that you've got No Escape and Fortress mixed up.
Fortress: 

Prison movie from the 90s - Yes
Sci fi future looking     - Yes
They could read the prisoners' minds - Yes
Somebody steals some bread and gets punished - No
Early stage of movie, they're on board a train and a guard says no talking - Trucks only in this movie

No Escape/Escape From Absolom:

Prison movie from the 90s - Yes
Sci fi future looking - For the first 15 - 20 mins, rest takes place on island
They could read the prisoners' minds -  No
Somebody steals some bread and gets punished - Yes
Early stage of movie, they're on board a train and a guard says no talking - About 3 mins in the guard on the train says to Ray Liotta "Eye forward" because Ray is looking out the window and prisoners aren't allowed to do that.


Where is the mind-reading bit in your summary?

There is a bit in "No Escape/Escape From Absolom" where the Warden is reading Ray Liotta's characters psych profile.  I don't know if that is what you are thinking off.  I've seen Fortress and Escape from Absolom a few times.  In Fortress, aren't any trains, they arrive by truck.  No Escape has every scene you mention above except for the mind reading scenes.  The only thing I can think of is the early scenes in No Escape take place in a futuristic prison very similiar to the one in Fortress.  But that is only for the first 20 mins or so of the movie before he gets sent to the island.

Please  update your answer with such information. But, to me, reading a psych profile doesn't sound like mind reading.

Do you remember anything else in the movie.  In Fortress, the prison is also a mine.  Does that ring a bell?

It isn't my question :)

Sorry then, I can't really help you.  I'm thinking you've got No Escape and Fortress mixed up.  If you had only mentioned a prison movie where they can read peoples minds, I would have said Fortress.  If you had said a prison movie with all those requirements except mind reading, I would have said No Escape (It's one of my favourite movies, I know a lot of the scenes of by heart).  There's not much to work on in your question.  I'll edit my answer a bit better

thank you so much. I am so sorry, i really messed it up in my memory, bacause i watched it about 10 years ago. It was "No escape". I appreciate your help.

That's OK.  Hopefully you get a chance to watch it again. Stuart Wilson has some great lines in it as the bad guy.

The only film that comes to my mind is Fortress. It's been a while since I've seen it but It's set in a futuristic prison where the mind control/wiping is used as punishment.
As i say it's been a while since i've seen it so I can't comment on individual scenes.
